# as3 MovieClip masking not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mask, masking

I'm having difficulties trying to add some masks

```
 mc1.mask = randMc;
```

Where mc1 = loaded MovieClip, and randMc is a pic imported to flash and converted as MovieClip.  This is a very big game code I have there so I thought the Indexes might be the problem so I added this :

```
setChildIndex(randMc, (getChildIndex(mc1)-1));
```

But it didn't work meaning the movieclip stays the same, it won't mask with randMc...
Any suggestions?

Note: I also have used scaleX/Y on mc1

Comment: When you say "it didn't work", what exactly didn't work.  Are you seeing everything that is under the mask but are expecting to see only see parts of the movieclip? Or are you not seeing anything.  I'm guessing that you are seeing everything since you are using a picture correct?

Comment: yes
...meaning the movieclip stays the same, it won't mask with randMc

Comment: Well, what it sounds like is that it _is_ masking the `MovieClip` just fine, but because your mask has every pixel filled, since it contains a picture, it is thereby showing you the entire MovieClip. Case in point, don't use pictures as a mask. You'll have to create your masks another way if you are trying to block out parts of your movieclip.

Comment: How? zzz it's a .png picture anyway but the pixels that are empty do "count"? That's why it won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that .png files are a mask including transparent pixels, so it's a square mask.. anyway I fixed it with

```
mc1.cacheAsBitmap  = true;
randMc.cacheAsBitmap  = true;
```

This way it the empty pixels won't "count" and the mask will be just like the imported .png on stage

Comment: Just an FYI, If the contents of `mc1` change, you will take a performance hit in the rendering of the graphics when you use `cacheAsBitmap`. Each time the MovieClip changes/updates, it has to perform the `cacheAsBitmap` again.